# Change Color of Unselected Tab Bar Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar controller and I've managed to make the selected tab image and title black and the unselected item titles white but I can't get the unselected item images to be white.

In my tab bar controller:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

```
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIColor *customColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:179.0/255.0f green:155.0/255.0f blue:107.0/255.0f alpha:1];

    [self.tabBar setBarTintColor:customColor];

    [self.tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UITabBarItem *item0 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

    item0.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_unselected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    item0.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_tab"];
    item1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"contact_unselected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    item1.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contact_tab"];
    item2.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"about_unselected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    item2.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"about_tab"];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like this:

tab bar controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIColor *customColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:179.0/255.0f green:155.0/255.0f blue:107.0/255.0f alpha:1];

    [self.tabBar setBarTintColor:customColor];
    [self.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

In each of the three view controllers on the tab bar:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Home", @"Home");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_unselected"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_tab"];
    }
    return self;
}
```